# Recovering an image from Gaussian Noise given random seed

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I've been trying to add reproducible Gaussian Noise by fixing a random seed, saving the image, reading the image and regenerate the Gaussian Noise, and 'subtracting' it to recover the original image. Here's the (pseudo-)code for what I've tried so far:

```py
SEED = 1234
np.random.seed(SEED)

img = cv2.imread(path, -1) # (32,32,3)
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=20, size=(32,32,3)).astype(np.uint8)

temp = img + noise

# ignore the noise if value exceeds 255 or is below 0
temp = np.where(temp<255, temp, img)
temp = np.where(temp>0, temp, img)

cv2.imwrite(some_path_and_file_name, temp)
```

Then, I read the image file with Gaussian Noise in the same way. When I 'ignore' the noise, I keep track of the matrix index of when the 'ignoring' happened, and use this information to recover the original data:

```
img = cv2.imread(path_to_noise_img, -1)

SEED = 1234
np.random.seed(SEED)
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=20, size=(32,32,3)).astype(np.uint8)

temp = img - noise

# flag is the matrix with the indices of 'ignoring'
recovered_img = np.where(flag == 0, temp, img)

cv2.imwrite(some_path_and_file_name, recovered_img)
```

However, when I open the two images, they are different. I have checked that the Gaussian Noise is the same all the time, and it feels like something is going wrong (some sort of irreversible conversion is happening) when I read or write the image file.

However, I am having trouble debugging this since I am new to Python.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**
I tried saving the image and loading the image using OpenCV function calls without modifying anything, and compared the values. From what I see, the values being read in are different. What should I fix in my code to prevent this from happening?

**Solution**
The code below worked like a charm (Thanks to all the comments and the answer).

```py
np.random.seed(SEED)

original = cv2.imread("C:/Users/user/project/1.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
n = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=20, size=original.shape).astype(np.int32)

n = original.astype(np.int32) + n.astype(np.int32)


floor = np.zeros_like(n)
ceil = np.zeros_like(n)

floor = np.where(n<255, 0, 1)

t = np.where(n < 255, n, original)

# record when rounding occurs
ceil = np.where(t>0, 0, 1)
arr = np.where(t>0, t, original)

flag = floor + ceil
arr = arr.astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/user/project/1-1.png", arr.astype(np.uint8))
```

```py
np.random.seed(SEED)

recover = cv2.imread("C:/Users/user/project/1-1.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED).astype(np.int32)
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=20, size=recover.shape).astype(np.int32)

ans = np.where(flag==0, recover-noise, recover)

assert(ans.astype(np.uint8) == original.astype(np.uint8)).all()
```

Comment: Maybe overflow of "uint8" addition?

Comment: @MarkLavin That's what I tried to catch with the 'flag' and np.where() conditions but I will check that again.

Comment: If the two images you're adding together are both "int8", then I believe the result will be "uint8" and therefore you will never see a value > 255.

Comment: @MarkLavin Your point is correct and I've fixed that (by converting it to "int32" and converting it back. But the problem with OpenCV functions seems to persist.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped.

Comment: @MarkLavin Oh, please don't be. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: To debug, pick a pixel that is different in the recovered image, and then look at the original pixel value, the noise added to it, and the noise removed to give a different result.

Comment: You aren’t saving the image to jpeg are you? Jpeg is lossy.

Comment: @balmy Apparently, yes. I’ve just switched to .png. Cv2 function is still lossy it seems though.

Comment: Use that same approach; Pick a pixel, etc… It’s not magic, the processing steps are quite logical and a similarly logical approach to analysing the difference must yield a result

Comment: @balmy Thanks! with the answer below and your comment, I wrote a code that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple issues...

### Compression

JPEG is a lossy compression, which means you will surely not be getting the exact same values back as you had before compression.

PNG is lossless, so it will give you the exact values you had before compression.

### Integer math

Adding two uint8 values results in an uint8 again.

That means your math will always result in values in the range of 0..255. uint8 values can **never** be <0 or >255.

Your `np.where` checks are useless because the values **are** uint8, and even after addition they stay uint8, and they can **never** be <0 or >255.

Further, whenever you add/subtract values, if the result exceeds the range, that has to be **handled** in some way. Numpy simply *wraps the values around*, as is usual with integer math. Another option is *to saturate*, meaning *to clip*. OpenCV functions tend to do that. You can produce either with either library, with some care.

If there is any saturating math in your code, you will definitely not be able to subtract the noise and recover the original image. If there is merely wrapping math in your code, you *can* recover the original image by subtracting the noise.

### Debugging

You are discarding so much information, reducing the answer to "*are* they bit-exact equal or not?"

You should use a small image, 3x3 pixels or something, and then **look at** the values, when you *print* those numpy arrays.

### Demo

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("image.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

SEED = 1234
np.random.seed(SEED)
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=20, size=img.shape).astype(np.uint8)

img_with_noise = img + noise # this will wrap around

cv.imwrite("image_with_noise.png", img_with_noise)
```

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("image.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img_with_noise = cv.imread("image_with_noise.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# generate noise the exact same way
SEED = 1234
np.random.seed(SEED)
noise = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=20, size=img.shape).astype(np.uint8)

img_recovered = img_with_noise - noise # wrapping around again, backwards

cv.imwrite("image_recovered.png", img_recovered)

# images should be equal in all values of all pixels
assert (img_recovered == img).all()
```